# How to free memory in document-based app upon document close?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory, document

I wrote a small document based application for OS X.

I see that every New document when created increases the memory usage (Xcode gauge) as expected, but when I close the document the memory usage is decreased only insignificantly.

Thus many New/Close operations produce memory leak ...

**How to explain the leak, and how to free the memory ?**

**Details:**

The application has a document which presents itself in a NSOutlineView with a million lines(big amount to demonstrate the memory usage change) containing the same string at every line.

Comment: `Close` is not the counterpart of `New`.

Comment: @ott-- Interesting note. Can you explain what does Close do with relation to the NSDocument and why doesn't it free the used memory ?

Comment: I'd rather use `NSDocument d = new ...` and later after the close simply a `d = nil;`. That should release the memory.